# IPC of C code with C# project running under Linux using Mono

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, lua, mono

I have a Unity3D project that I'm exporting to linux using Mono. I need this project to communicate (fast) with another project running on the same linux machine, written in Lua (which can also run C code).
What is the best way to do that? Currently I'm planning to use Sockets. 
Thanks!

Comment: Use IPC like pipes; shared memory; mailslots for local machine because they're faster

Comment: Can you refer me to some code or tutorial? I can't find any that specifically deals with Unity3d (or Mono) on Linux.

Comment: sockets are fine, it's incredibly unlikely you will need more performance than that.